# How to check pull timestamp of a certain commit in git

Tags: git, logging, timestamp, pull

Is there a way to determine the timestamp of when was a certain commit was pulled in my server? If so, kindly let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to  me what you mean by this.  Note that the *command* `git pull` is essentially just a wrapper for two other commands, `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or followed by `git rebase` if you set or specify that option).  There are also two timestamps in every commit, the *commiter* timestamp and the *author* timestamp.

Comment: Usually when you type git log <the-commit-id> it will show something like this:

commit sha1
Author: John Doe
Date:   Thu May 19 12:32:12 2016 +0900

Do you know if that "Date" info was a committer timestamp or an author timestamp?

Comment: Basically I just want to know when was a certain commit was deployed into a server

Comment: The default is to show the committer timestamp.  You can use, e.g., `git log --format=fuller` to see more.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not store timestamps of when commits were pulled/fetched.
However, it **may** be possible to check at which time the git object for that commit was created in the git object data base.

Get the full sha1 of the desired commit. For example, if we're checking the latest commit on the master branch:

```
> git rev-parse master
10bc990ba54b4387e4d1ec3508effee0b3f0b371
```

Take this name and add a slash after the first two hex digits:

```
10/bc990ba54b4387e4d1ec3508effee0b3f0b371
```

List the corresponding file in the git object data base (assuming *nix):

```
> ls -l .git/objects/10/bc990ba54b4387e4d1ec3508effee0b3f0b371
-r--r--r-- 1 username username 168 jun 16 13:12 objects/10/bc990ba54b4387e4d1ec3508effee0b3f0b371
```

This is not a foolproof method though. Commit objects may have been moved into packfiles, and in that case, the file mentioned above will not exist.